# Are there rules of thumb for selecting images for a supervised learning training set?

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning, computer-vision

**Background**

I have a fairly small image set (about 300 images) and I need to detect rectangular plates present in these images. Each of the images are annotated, but some examples are clearer than others due to lighting conditions (after pre-processing). The articles which I've read on supervised learning only go so far as to say that I need annotated images.

**Questions**

I'd like to find some rules of thumb for picking annotated images. For example, I have the following questions:

1. Should I include obstructed annotations in my training set?
2. Should I include annotations that I cannot make out myself due to lighting conditions?
3. Is it bad if, inside the image set, I have unlabelled examples of wrenches? I.e. will this confuse my network?
4. Should I augment the training set by performing rotations, even if I only expect to see horizontally aligned rectangular plates?

**Implementation**

I'm using the Python implementation of Faster-RCNN with VGG16. The setup is described [here](https://huangying-zhan.github.io/2016/09/22/detection-faster-rcnn.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would generally use all the data available even if some is noisy, unless some of it was obviously nonsense.

> 1. Should I include obstructed annotations in my training set?

Yes, include obstructed images even though they are more challenging.

> 2. Should I include annotations that I cannot make out myself due to lighting conditions?

If you believe the annotations are still accurate then yes.

> 3. Is it bad if, inside the image set, I have unlabelled examples of wrenches? I.e. will this confuse my network?

Having unlabelled positive examples is called label noise and it'll make object recognition harder. If possible try to fix unlabelled examples by adding the missing annotations. But I would still include these labels, especially if you think this will be a feature of the dataset where you wish to apply this.

> 4. Should I augment the training set by performing rotations, even if I only expect to see horizontally aligned rectangular plates?

I am unsure if this is best here, but I am inclined to think it wouldn't hurt. That said you can start with the usual augmentation methods such as horizontal flips, random crops, and adding some noise by Gaussian blurring or playing with hue or saturation. If you are not getting the performance you are after then consider more intensive data augmentation such as rotations and other affine transformations.  One of the intuitions about data augmentation is that it helps prevent overfitting by letting the neural network learn from a wider set of spatial statistics, this is relevant given your small dataset. Also consider adapting your preprocessing step to do further augmentation.

Comment: +1 for answering all of my questions. I will definitely heed your advice about augmenting the set. I've heard conflicting answers from colleagues for things like labelling obstructed objects. Do you know of any papers or references that can provide data? I've personally tried masking out the obstructed objects from the set to avoid confusing the network, but I didn't notice a significant improvement.

Comment: I had a look for some papers about dealing with occlusion, but they seem by and large quite topic specific. Have a look here 
 to get an example of what I mean: https://pure.tugraz.at/portal/files/7666396/opitz_eccv_16.pdf if you are interested. Humans have problems doing object detection with occlusion too so I think an open problem as to how best to handle it with CNNs.

Comment: That's a very interesting paper, thanks for pointing that out. I did some minor augmentation (-2 and +2 degree rotations) seems to work well--maybe because that's the typical variation in alignment that I see.